# PSTricks and \pscustom

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following example:

**Code**

```
% latex filename.tex
% dvips filename.dvi
% ps2pdf filename.ps

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.9,-3.9)(3.8,0.15)
  \pscustom[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = lightgray
  ]{%
    \psarc(0,0){3.53}{180}{360}
    \psarc(-3.74,0){0.21}{0}{180}
    \psarc(0,0){3.95}{180}{360}
    \psarc(3.74,0){0.21}{0}{180}
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Question**

How do I make PSTricks fill only the enclosed area (the horizontal line isn't there if you remove `\pscustom`)?

Comment: may be add title/reason for the edit to make it clear and catchy for others

Comment: @texenthusiast I just made the initial code simpler. `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `pscustom` it's best to have the starting point and ending point match together; indeed, the reason that you are getting the unexpected result is that `PSTricks` is connecting the first and last points together- in your code, the first and last points are far away from each other, hence the unwanted horizontal line.

I switched the order of a few of your `psarc` segments, and also changed the direction of some of them from counter clockwise to clockwise using `psarcn` to keep everything flowing in the same direction.

While debugging, I found it helpful to colour the different segments, and use arrows to show the direction:

[image]

Once everything matched, up, adding `pscustom` back in gave the result as expected:

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: true}
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,1)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray]{%
        \psarc[linecolor=blue]{->}(0,0){3.53}{180}{360}
        \psarcn[linecolor=orange]{->}(3.74,0){0.21}{180}{0}
        \psarcn[linecolor=green]{->}(0,0){3.95}{360}{180}
        \psarcn[linecolor=red]{->}(-3.74,0){0.21}{180}{0}
    }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

You'll note that I have left the colours and arrows in the code- just remove them when you're happy with what's going on.

As noted by Werner, in this particular case you might get the same output using `ncarcbox`, which is detailed on p68 of [`the documentation`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks).

PS: I've also used the [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) tool to help with `shell escape`.

Comment: Great answer. In this, very particular case, [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) also provides `\ncarcbox` that creates a similar shape. See p 68 of the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf).

Comment: @Werner thanks, I appreciate the compliment :) I had wondered if there was something a built-in way of doing it- I'll add it to my answer :)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

As Werner already wrote use `\ncarcbox`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,1)
\pnodes(-3.5,0){A}(3.5,0){B}
\ncarcbox[nodesep=0.2,boxsize=0.2,linearc=0.2,arcangle=90,
     fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```